# Which mantra/s can be chanted after initiation?

Tags: mantras, guru, initiation

I have recently read that mantras cannot be chanted before initiation.
I am aware that during initiation, a guru will give a mantra in the ears of the disciple.

My question is, can the person initiated only chant the mantra given by the guru (and other mantras given by the guru) or can one chant all mantras in the scriptures?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That particular mantra becomes the Diksha mantra/ Guru mantra but at the same the disciple becomes qualified to chant many more mantras .. the Guru can clarify more about this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Rickross